# Python Asyncio/Await: Having Trouble understanding the effect of await within a loop

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

**Code Block B** is from an Asyncio/Aiohttp [Tutorial Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nFn4_nA_yk8) I am trying to follow along

Quick Description:

`The async function (The "coroutine") loops through a list of ticker symbols making API call requests for each symbol.`

## CODE BLOCK B

```
# GETTING MARKET DATA via API REQUESTS

######  SETUP STUFF  ######
api_key =  os.getenv('ALPHAVANTAGE_API_KEY')
url = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=OVERVIEW&symbol={}&apikey={}'

symbols = ['AAPL' , 'GOOG', 'TSLA', 'MSFT', 'AAPL' , 'DWAC' , 'VAXX' , 'MRNA' , 'JNJ']
results = []
######  SETUP STUFF  ######



async def get_symbols_async():
    ##########################
    session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
    for symbol in symbols:
        print('Working on:   {}'.format(symbol))
        CR = session.get(url.format(symbol, api_key), ssl=False)
        # CR:       Creates/Is a Coroutine function & does nothing by itself.
        response = await CR
        # AWAIT:    Throws Coroutine in the EVENT LOOP, where they can then run/ be executed.
        #           ... where Coroutines can MAKE & RETURN Calls.
    await session.close()
    ##########################


asyncio.run(get_symbols_async())
```

He says: `at the end of each iteration within the for loop, the main program/thread has to wait for the response.`

The ***await*** in Code block **A** didn't hold up / pause the execution of the next print line.

#####################  QUESTION

What I'm seeing is a builtin *threading.join()* equivalent mechanism in play here. I just don't know why or where it's coming from since I don't know the internal workings of the event loop.

I thought the keyword `await` placed coroutines into the event loop where they are then queued/scheduled to run/execute ie send out whatever I/O calls. At first I thought this was a misleading keyword since an await statement *starts* Coroutines, where the response quietly gets stored in its assigned variable (the variable: "response" in this case) without interupting the main, unless the main requires the return value before it is ready. So where exactly is the hangup?

Why is the main thread is being affected/stopped at the end of each for loop iteration (according to guy in video)?

#####################  QUESTION

## CODE BLOCK A

```
async def greet():
    ##########################
    print('welcome')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('Hello')
    ##########################

asyncio.run(greet())
```

seems to pass the coroutine into the event loop without holding up the main.

Comment: I thought await told the event loop that the coroutine could be suspended at that point and give other coroutines/task a chance to do stuff. If there are no other tasks it wouldn't be suspended.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-runner.html#asyncio.run

Answer (score 0):

The object that follows the await keyword is not necessarily a coroutine, but  it can be any *awaitable* object.  Coroutines are awaitable objects but there are others, such as `asyncio.Future`.  It is true that awaiting a coroutine is one way of causing it to begin execution, but I don't think it's fair to say that await is therefore a misleading bit of terminology.  In all cases it does what it implies: it *waits* for the awaitable object to enter its "done" state.  If it's awaiting a coroutine, the code doesn't proceed until the coroutine has finished execution and becomes "done."  While an await expression is waiting, other tasks get a chance to run.  If the awaitable is already done and there are no other tasks that are ready to run, there is very little delay at all.

In your code block A, asyncio.sleep(1) returns coroutine object that does nothing but doesn't become "done" for 1 second.  So the task gets suspended for one second.

You say that the video said, "at the end of each iteration within the for loop, the main program/thread has to wait for the response."  Yes, it will wait for `CR` to become "done."  What is CR?  How long will it take to become "done"?  If CR is the result of a simple web transaction it might be done in only a few milliseconds.  That's still "waiting for a response" but it won't be easy to see.  You can measure the delay like this:

```
t0 = time.time()
response = await CR
print(time.time() - t0)
```

You will see how long the await was, in seconds.

Comment: reply to @PaulCornelius statement:  

`"In your code block A, asyncio.sleep(1) returns coroutine object that does nothing but doesn't become "done" for 1 second. So the task gets suspended for one second."`  
  
Yes, when I run (**code block A**), the program indeed does not finish/complete/conclude until the 1s has passed. But in that example code block I was referring to the fact that both print statements execute one right after the other, no 1sec wait.  
  
The `await` statement passed the coroutine into evt_loop & was nonblocking. Why is the stuff in the for loop blocking?

Comment: I don't think we're communicating at all.  In code block A there is certainly a 1 second delay between the two print statements, and in code block B there is only 1 print statement.  So I don't understand your comment.  The stuff in the for loop is not blocking the main thread, it is awaiting on CR.  That does not block the thread since the event loop continues to run.  I cannot explain what some guy in YouTube video was talking about, sorry.  You'll have to ask him.